# KSQLDB client for .net

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have searched google but couldn't find any .net client for KSQLDB.

Is there any? An official one?

Answer (score 2):

There are some community-created clients:

- https://github.com/tomasfabian/Kafka.DotNet.ksqlDB
- https://github.com/alex-basiuk/ksqlDB-client-dotnet

See also https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/pull/6883/

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure if any of these can be used in production!

Comment: @DixitSingla Can I ask why?  Is it the licences?  (I haven't checked)

Comment: My client wanted an official one provided by confluent!